# How to make an asynchronous tornado handler?

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado

I have been trying to make an asynchronous tornado handler, but with no success yet.

I read and tried the [examples](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html) in documentation.

Here is the documented example:

```
# localhost:8888/test
class GenAsyncHandler(RequestHandler):
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
        do_something_with_response(response)
        self.render("template.html")
```

I replaced this part:

```
        response = yield http_client.fetch("http://example.com")
```

with this:

```
        response = yield gen.Task(self.test())
```

where `self.test()` code is:

```
def test(callback):
    while(True):
        pass
```

I have another **IndexHandler** that should just print `hello async`, but it doesn't work because it seems the infinite loop in `self.test()` blocked the request which AFAIK this means it's not asynchronous.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Takes a function (and optional additional arguments) and runs it with
>   those arguments **plus a callback keyword argument**.

http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/gen.html#tornado.gen.Task